# Is it possible to set format date for all columns in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Property `AutoGenerateColumns` is set in `true`.
Column with date could have different indexes.

```
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
        DataTable tableD = new DataTable();
        tableD.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        adapter.SelectCommand = oracleCom;
        adapter.Fill(tableD);
        tableResults.DataSource = tableD.AsDataView();
        tableResults.DataBind();
```

Columns with date type values are get from different tables in db. And they have different names.

Comment: "Column with date could have different indexes" What do you mean?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, please elaborate.

Comment: You cannot specify the datatype for your columns in a grid view.

Comment: I assume that OP does not know which columns contain date fields but he wants to format them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) to format your columns.

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            { 
                DateTime dt = row.Field<DateTime>(col);
                e.Row.Cells[col.Ordinal].Text = dt.ToString("D");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[**Standard Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

If `AutoGenerateColumns` would set to `false` you could use the [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property on the `BoundFields` instead.